# How to get ip address from known mac address on Linux using Python

Tags: python, linux, networking

How would I find the ip address if I know the mac address of a machine?

Comment: Why did you ask a question for reply to it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a real question.

Comment: I didn't ask a question for a REPLY. I posted this question with an answer wiki-style, which is allowed on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to be able to do this, so I wrote a python script that can do it:

```
import scapy
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool

def _arp_request(ip_addr):
    answer, _ = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_addr), verbose=0, timeout=.5)
    if answer:
        return (answer[0][1].src, answer[0][0].pdst)

pool = Pool(50)
mac_addrs = [ad for ad in pool.map(_arp_request, addrs) if ad]
```

addrs is a list of possible ip addresses to try.

It makes rapid arp requests and maps out the network.

Or you could use the module that I wrote (which keeps a cache to minimize the arp requests):

```
>>> from ethip import ethip
>>> print ethip.getip('00:1E:C9:56:3C:8E', '10.5.42.255')
10.5.42.3
```

Comment: Is it answer for your question ? if not then move this text to your question.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to do it (there's no reliable way) it just provides a link to your code.

Comment: I flagged this answer for moderator attention.

Comment: It was my intention to provide a solution to other users of stackoverflow. When you ask a question, there is an option to answer in a wiki style. That's what I'm doing here. I'll post more code for a more detailed answer.

Comment: I fixed the answer to be more useful. Please review.

Comment: There's gotta be a better way than to use Scapy, which will probably require root privileges.

Comment: You can't send an arp request without root privileges. There is no better way. For example, you'll notice that the ping command ALWAYS runs as root. The permissions bit is set to execute as the owner.